# md5 to integer bits in python

Tags: python, hash

I'm trying to convert an MD5 hashed value into a a bit integer in python. Does anyone have any idea how I would go about doing this?

I currently go through several ngrams applying a hash to each ngram:

```
for sentence in range(0,len(doc)):
        for i in range(len(doc[sentence]) - 4 + 1):
            ngram = doc[sentence][i:i + 4]
            hashWord = hashlib.md5()
            hashWord.update(ngram)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably me - but what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't word it very well. I want to turn the hash into bits. I'm just not really sure how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If by "into bits", you mean a bit string for instance, then something like:

```
import hashlib

a = hashlib.md5('alsdkfjasldfjkasdlf')
b = a.hexdigest()
as_int = int(b, 16)
print bin(as_int)[2:]
# 11110000110010001100111010111001011010101011110001010000011010010010100111100
```

Comment: I think he maybe just wants a big int ... but not sure ...(+1 all the same) either way he should be able to get his answer here

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yup - I was thinking that, and if that's the case, the OP can work with `as_int`... The bitstring was just an example

Comment: Wow, this takes me back.  Getting an integer from a hash was the [very first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612150/python-256bit-hash-function-with-number-output/4612189#4612189) I answered on SO!

Comment: @DSM wow! Well, with 20k on the clock you've come a long way since then!

Comment: Clements, you hero, you. That's exactly what I was looking for. A correct answer tick to you, sir!

Comment: You need to make it encode it as `hashlib.md5(b'alsdkfjasldfjkasdlf')` or `hashlib.md5('alsdkfjasldfjkasdlf'.encode())`